# Spells similar to Unconcious Agenda for 3.5 without certain restrictions

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-death, poison

I'm after a spell i can have cast on my character where on a certain condition (in my case, character is bitten by a vampire) he will conscious or not, be made to perform an action (in my case, slug a poison vial).

This spell exists in pathfinder but has the condition that it cannot force the target to kill them self (which means it's nonviable for me).

If there's a better method/spell for it, i'll go with that other wise i'll just ask the dm to allow UA with some modifications in this instance.

Comment: What is your objective with the spell? Is it merely programmed suicide after a vampire attack? Or are you looking for ways to protect against vampires?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### *Contingency*, Poison Spell, and the melee touch spell of your choice

The Poison Spell feat from *Drow of the Underdark* allows you to apply the effects of any contact or injury poison to the target of the modified melee touch attack spell. So pick an appropriate melee touch attack spell, say *resistance* for ease of access, and have a *contingency* upon being bitten by a vampire to cast *poisoned resistance* on yourself.

Depending on interpretation, the poison may be absorbed into the spell at the time that you cast *contingency*, eliminating the risk of you losing or being unable to access the poison vial. And almost **nothing** stops *contingency*.

Comment: Good answer, thanks.
I knew i'd seen something like that spell but couldn't remember it's name making it difficult to search for, the poison spell feat is just icing, cheers.